# Can't get Slider to print different Text between intervals

Tags: if-statement, dart, flutter, slider

I want to print a different Texts in multiple intervals of a Slider

If (value > 0 && value < 3){text1}

If (value > 3 && value < 5){text2}

If (value > 5 && value < 8){text3}

If (value > 8 && value < 10){text4}

I know how i try is completely wrong. I would appreciate if someone explained how should i set up such an event.

```
String vaker = '';
  double _value = (0.0);

  void _setValue(double value)
   => setState(() => _value = value){
    if (_value> 0.0 && _value < 0.3)
      setState((){
        vaker = 'Egy nappal előre kapja a HáVéGét';
      });
};
```

---

```
new Slider(
    value: (_value),
    onChanged: _setValue,
    activeColor: Colors.orange,
    inactiveColor: Colors.white,
          ),
  new Text('${(vaker)}'),
```

Hope you understand what I'm trying to do. 
Thanx in advance for every advice!

Comment: could you add more code?

Comment: new Slider(
   min: 0.0,
   max: 10.0,
   divisions: 100,
   value: (sValue),
     onChanged: (newValue){
     setState(() {
     sValue=newValue;
     if (sValue >= 0.0 && sValue <= 3.0) {
     sFokozat = 'txt1';
     }
                    if (sValue >= 3.1 && sValue <= 5.0) {
                      sFokozat = 'txt2';
                    }
                    if (sValue >= 5.1 && sValue <= 10.0) {
                      sFokozat = 'txt3';
                    }

                  });
                }
              ),

Comment: i figured it out how it can work :)